# Blender collision activation only once

Tags: game-engine, collision

I have it so that once you touch this block, my voice actress begins giving a tutorial, but if you touch it again, she starts all over again, do you know a way to make this happen only once?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add a boolean property which is *False* by default. On collision, set it to *True* and play the sound only on collision AND if the property is equal to *False*.
2. Change the state on collision. States behave like layers, only the current active state(s) get executed. For a detailed explanation see: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/game_engine/logic/states.html

[image: Logic Bricks Setup]